# How to add actions to admin page with non-ascii charecters

Tags: django, admin, non-ascii-characters

I have this code which works fine in Django admin page, but is there a way to keep action name in Russian but function name in English?

```
actions = ["Отправить_сообщение"]  # add action to list page

def Отправить_сообщение(self, request, queryset):
    pass
```

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, see here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#writing-action-functions

For your code:

```py
actions = ["my_action"]

def my_action(self, request, queryset):
    pass

my_action.short_description = "Отправить сообщение"
```

Another way (better if you handle multiple languages) is to use the [internationalization framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/).